# Winsock bind not failing on bound port

Tags: windows-7, mingw, winsock

I recently have a very weird erroneous behavior and I can't explain why that is the case. I wrote for myself a networking library (still work in progress). Today my unit tests failed, because an other application had the ports in use. This is to be expected, but it did **not** fail as expected. I am looking at the result of `bind()` and that was 0.

```
handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
address.sin_port = htons(port);
if (bind(handle, (const sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
{
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to bind socket");
}
```

(Here is the [full code](https://github.com/rioki/spdr/blob/master/spdr/UdpSocket.cpp).)

My experience says `bind()` will return an error if the port it in use. Am I basically mistaken?

For details, we are talking about winsock on Windows 7; built with MinGW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue I was seeing was not part of bind failing. Sorry for stupidly posting this question; but it was driving me nuts..

Nevertheless netstat said the port was in use, although TCP...

Comment: A port can be used independently by both TCP and UDP at the same time without interfering with each other.

Comment: True. I did not think about that. That was why I was first mislead.